# Only allow to view a page that is redirected from example.com/login

Tags: php

I want a page that can be only accessible who is redirected from `example.com/login`

As example, if I directly visit `example.com/alice.php` it will redirect me to an error page. `example.com/alice.php` can be only accessible if a visitor was redirected from `example.com/login` .

How can I do that with php?

Comment: use cookies perhaps - if the cookie does not exist send them to login

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: you can use session as well

Comment: Set a session and check for that session, or alternatively, use cookies and check for that cookie. If the session or cookie does not exist, you redirect them to the error page.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can use this as:

```
<?php
//your-url-which-you-do-not-what-direct access
$url != 'http://example.com/alice.php';

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == $url) {
  header('Location: http://example.com/error.php'); //redirect to some other page
  exit();
}

?>
```